# Easy way to filter elements from a collection in Java?

Tags: java, collections

I want to write a method that removes all elements from a collection that follow a certain pattern. In functional languages, I would use **filter()** with a lambda expression. However, in Java, it seems I'm stuck with this:

```
public void removeAllBlueCars() {
    LinkedList<Car> carsToRemove = new LinkedList<Car>();
    for (Car c : cars) {
        if (c.getCarColor() == Color.BLUE) {
            carsToRemove.add(c);
        }
    }
    cars.removeAll(carsToRemove );
}
```

Removing elements directly causes a ConcurrentModificationException. Is there a better way to do this without resorting to [Google Collections](http://code.google.com/p/google-collections/)?

Comment: And you do not want to use google collections why? BTW, http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/ is the new google collections...

Comment: I love Google Collections/Guava, however my question was precisely do find out how to do this *without* resorting to libraries.

Comment: I'm either amused or disturbed by this notion that heavily-tested and heavily-used libraries are things we "resort to", presumably in a tearful moment of weakness. :-)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could iterate through the list using a [`ListIterator`](http://cupi2.uniandes.edu.co/site/images/recursos/javadoc/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html), which has a [remove](http://cupi2.uniandes.edu.co/site/images/recursos/javadoc/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#remove()) method.

Btw you should declare your list as `List<Car>` - program for interfaces, not implementation.

Comment: @Steve, correct. At first quick reading, I perceived that `ListIterator.remove` offers additional guarantees over the base interface's method, but at second check I see that I misunderstood. So you are right, an `Iterator` would suffice.

Answer (score 22):

With Java 8, you can filter with a lambda expression using [`Collection.removeIf`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#removeIf-java.util.function.Predicate-).

```
cars.removeIf(c -> c.getCarColor() == Color.BLUE);
```

Answer (score 16):

Maybe you could use iterators, which are a little more efficient:

```
public void removeAllBlueCars() {
    Iterator<Car> carsIterator = cars.iterator();
    while (carsIterator.hasNext()) {
        Car c = carsIterator.next();
        if (c.getCarColor() == Color.BLUE) {
            carsIterator.remove();
        }
    }
}
```

---

Also, if you want to make this solution more generic, I'd suggest you something like:

```
public interface Filter<T> {

    public boolean shouldRemove(T t);

}
```

And you could use it like this:

```
public void removeCars(Filter<Car> filter) {
    Iterator<Car> carsIterator = cars.iterator();
    while (carsIterator.hasNext()) {
        Car c = carsIterator.next();
        if (filter.shouldRemove(c)) {
            carsIterator.remove();
        }
    }
}
```

Your method gets called like this:

```
removeCars(new Filter<Car>() {

    public boolean shouldRemove(Car car) {
        return car.getCarColor() == Color.BLUE;
    }

});
```

Comment: Nice way if you do not want to use google collections or lmbadaj

Answer (score 5):

You can use [CollectionUtils.filter()](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-3.2.1/org/apache/commons/collections/CollectionUtils.html#filter%28java.util.Collection,%20org.apache.commons.collections.Predicate%29). It works with an `Iterator`, so it should have no problems removing items directly from the `Collection`. It is another dependency though. If you want the code standalone it would be:

```
public interface Predicate {
    boolean evaluate(Object o);
}

public static void filter(Collection collection, Predicate predicate) {
if ((collection != null) && (predicate != null))
    for (Iterator it = collection.iterator(); it.hasNext(); )
        if (!predicate.evaluate(it.next()))
            it.remove();
}
...
filter(collection, new Predicate() {
    public boolean evaluate(Object o) { return whatever; }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is the Android way to implement a generic solution for this:

### Usage:

Remove all null strings from my list

```
    LinkedList<String> list = ...
    ListUtils.filter(list, new ListUtils.Filter<String>() {
        @Override
        public boolean keepItem(String item) {
            return item != null;
        }
    });
```

### Source:

```
public class ListUtils {
    public interface Filter<T>{
        boolean keepItem(T item);
    }

    public static <T> void filter(@NonNull List<T> items, @NonNull Filter<T> filter) {
        for (Iterator<T> iterator = items.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();){
            if(!filter.keepItem(iterator.next())){
                iterator.remove();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

See if [lambdaj](http://code.google.com/p/lambdaj/wiki/LambdajFeatures#Filtering_on_a_condition)'s filter option can help you.

Answer (score 3):

You could always go backwards and delete the elements..

```
    for (int i = array.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
       if (array.get(i).getCarColor() == Color.BLUE)
                array.remove(i);
    }
```

edit: Noticed it was a LinkedList which might make my answer a bit non-relevant.

Comment: No, A linkedlist can have indexes and anything. your solution is correct and short

Comment: @vodkhang, but its performance is terrible for big lists - O(n^2).

Comment: Ah yeah, I now noticed that it is O(n^2) because the remove method takes another O(n), and the loop is O(n) already.

Comment: That was what i was thinking. :)
It is (n²) for both LinkedLists and ArrayLists, but if you just want short easy-to-read code, this  might be a "good" choice.

Comment: Using the iterator seems the right thing to do without resorting to libraries. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I'm a big fan of the Iterator solution provided by Vivien Barousse and gpeche.  But I wanted to point out that you don't have to actually remove any elements from the collection, you just need to prevent the filter from returning them.  That way, you basically have multiple views of the same collection, which can be very convenient and efficient.  The Filter object is basically your lamda expression, or as close as you're gonna get in Java until version 7...

Answer (score 2):

It's really an old post but how abt using the way given in Oracle Java tutorial.

```
static void filter(Collection<?>c) {
    for (Iterator<?>it = c.iterator(); it.hasNext(); )
         if (!cond(it.next()))
             it.remove();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static <T> void filter(List<T> list, Predicate<? super T> removeIf) {
    if(list == null) return;

    Iterator<T> iterator = list.iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        if (removeIf.apply(iterator.next())) iterator.remove();
    }
}
```

Pass a list of some generic type to this function with a predicate to remove unwanted elements.

Answer (score 1):

With Java8 introducing [lambda expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html), it's much easier to implement filtering on a collection in a more functional approach.

I wrote an example for you. Please also note how nicer it is to print Collection content using forEach:

```
public class Java8Filtering {

    public static void main(String[] argc) {
        LinkedList<Car> cars = new LinkedList<>();
        cars.add(new Car("car 1", Color.BLUE));
        cars.add(new Car("car 2", Color.GREEN));
        cars.add(new Car("car 3", Color.RED));
        cars.add(new Car("car 4", Color.BLUE));

        List<Car> filteredCars = cars.stream()
                .filter(car -> car.getCarColor() != Color.BLUE)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        filteredCars.forEach(car -> System.out.println("Car: " + car.getCarName() + " with color: " + car.getCarColor()));
    }
}

class Car {

    private Color carColor;
    private String carName;

    public Car(String carName, Color carColor) {
        this.carName = carName;
        this.carColor = carColor;
    }

    public Color getCarColor() {
        return carColor;
    }

    public void setCarColor(Color carColor) {
        this.carColor = carColor;
    }

    public String getCarName() {
        return carName;
    }

    public void setCarName(String carName) {
        this.carName = carName;
    }
}

enum Color {
    BLUE, GREEN, RED
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For those of you who come across this thread and might be working on Android with RxJava/RxAndroid, there's a quick way to do this without adding the Apache Commons Collections dependency:

```
cars = Observable.from(cars).filter(car -> {
  if (car.getCarColor() == Color.BLUE) {
    return false;
  }

  return true;
}).toList().toBlocking().first();
```

Note that I also happen to be using lambda expressions with [Retrolambda](https://github.com/evant/gradle-retrolambda). If you aren't using Retrolambda, you can express the same thing using the following:

```
cars = Observable.from(cars).filter(new Func1<Car, Boolean>() {
      @Override
      public Boolean call(Car car) {
        if (car.getCarColor() == Color.BLUE) {
          return false;
        }

        return true;
      }
}).toList().toBlocking().first();
```